# Android.mk PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY how to generate LOCAL_SRC_FILES file from script?

Tags: android, makefile, android-ndk, ndk-build

I have an NDK project where I build the shared libraries using the cross-compiler and standard gnu make utils.  That is done with a separate script.  But for the purpose of using the libraries in my project, I would like my `Android.mk` process to call my script to generate the shared library if it hasn't already been built, and then have `Android.mk` wrap it using the `PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY` process.

Currently, if I run my script offline to generate `libmy_so.so`, then the following makefile will work.  However, if I don't run the script explicitly first, I get the following error:

`Android NDK: ERROR:/path_to_project/Android.mk:my_module: LOCAL_SRC_FILES points to a missing file`

and my script is never called, so the make process is failing before even trying to resolve the dependency.

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE        := my_module
LOCAL_SRC_FILES     := libmy_so.so
LOCAL_EXPORT_CFLAGS := # some stuff
LOCAL_EXPORT_LDLIBS := # some stuff
$(LOCAL_PATH)/libmy_so.so:
    echo "generate file"
    $(shell run_script_that_creates_libmy_so.so)

include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Is there a clean solution to this?  I am even ok with running the script automatically as a preprocessing step (I can always have my script quietly exit if the file exists already), but I have not found an incantation that allows the `LOCAL_SRC_FILES` variable to point to a non-existent file.  I have considered placing a dummy `libmy_so.so` to start, but that is an ugly hack.

Comment: I think you should config ndk in build.gradle and let one depend on what it need.

Comment: I can't really use build.gradle directly for this because I am creating an extensible tool that is supposed to make working with the NDK easier.  See [this project](https://github.com/ericwlange/hemroid) to see what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Found a hack -- better way?**

I found a hack.  The makefile `prebuilt-library.mk` in the NDK contains the following lines:

```
ifndef prebuilt
$(call __ndk_info,ERROR:$(LOCAL_MAKEFILE):$(LOCAL_MODULE): LOCAL_SRC_FILES points to a missing file)
$(call __ndk_info,Check that $(prebuilt_path) exists, or that its path is correct)
$(call __ndk_error,Aborting)
#endif
```

I created a copy of this file (and `prebuilt-shared-library.mk` to which I reference my copy of `prebuilt-library.mk`) and commented those lines out to stop the error.  Then the trick is to make some target that is evaluated first depend on the file I want to generate.  After digging through the .mk scripts in the NDK, I found that `libraries` serves the purpose.  By adding `libraries: $(LOCAL_PATH)/libmy_so.so` to `Android.mk`, it will finally do what I want.

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE        := my_module
LOCAL_SRC_FILES     := libmy_so.so
LOCAL_EXPORT_CFLAGS := # some stuff
LOCAL_EXPORT_LDLIBS := # some stuff
$(LOCAL_PATH)/libmy_so.so:
    echo "generate file"
    $(shell run_script_that_creates_libmy_so.so)
libraries: $(LOCAL_PATH)/libmy_so.so

include /path/to/my/mk/files/prebuilt-shared-library.mk
```

This is obviously less than ideal as I would like to make sure my makefiles mature with newer versions of the NDK, but it does the trick.  Still interested in more elegant solutions.